# Strategies for changing saved app data format without breaking existing saves (JavaScript+IndexedDB)

Tags: javascript, json, persistence, indexeddb

I have an app that indexes thousands of files and stores information about the files and how they relate in JSON format on the user's computer. I'm using JavaScript and IndexedDB. The important points are the data *isn't* stored in a central database I control, it must be in JSON format and there's lots of data.

As I add more features in the future, it's likely I'll want to change the JSON format e.g. adding new fields, renaming fields, normalising data that wasn't normalised before.

I haven't released the app yet and I'm nervous about doing so because 1) if I change the data format, I have to be careful I don't break loading of data in the previous format 2) having to account for old data formats will slow down how aggressively I can change the app.

Are there any strategies I can use to lessen the impact file format changes have on my development speed and risk of bugs?

Answer (score 1):

That's why you have to specify a version when you open the database. Then if your schema changes, increment the version and write code in your `onupgradeneeded` handler to deal with altering the stored data from old versions.

Answer (score 1):

What dumbmatter said, but another thing to consider is to store a version field in the object itself. Read this in first, then dynamically determine how to interpret the object's other fields.